# how to read the string from file using RandomAccessFile?

Tags: java, string, randomaccessfile

my file content contains four columns

**001  mike 1122 98

002  stephen 1232 97**

Using **RandomAccessFile** i need to store the each column in its respective array types.

readInt() is used to read Integer of column 1

how can i read the strings(column 2) to store in string array?

Comment: if we use readUTF() it shows EOFException.

Answer (score 0):

what about using readline

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readLine()

and then using a tokenizer to identify you cells

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

and then populating your arrays ?

(in that case the RandomAccessFile is probably overkill)